# RavenDb LuceneQuery Suggest search

Tags: ravendb

I would like to attempt to take advantage of the Suggest feature in RavenDb. Is it possible to do this when using a *session.Advanced.LuceneQuery*?

I am using the Advanced option as I'm indexing in a multi-map scenario where the return type is not known, which prevents using the strongly typed Linq querying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using LuceneQuery, you need to call the store.DatabaseCommands.Suggest() yourself.